# grepl for dplyr sql table?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, grepl

is there a workaround to use something like

```
filter(df, grepl("A|B|C",location))
```

for a dplyr SQL table? In SQL it is probalby a `LIKE`. Of cource I could convert the SQL table to a R data table, but it is very large. (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html) At the moment I get

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement) : 
  error in statement: no such function: GREPL
```

thx
Christof

Comment: Use SQL `IN`. http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-IN.asp

Comment: `filter(df, location %in% c("a", "b", "c")`, or use a `semi_join()`

Comment: @hadley thx for your brilliant libraries. Is there a way to get also pattern matching (SQL LIKE instead of IN)? `%in%`and `semi_join()`do exact matching, if I understood it correctly

Comment: Use `x %like% y`

Comment: Where are these operators documented?

Comment: @dorvak `?translate_sql`or direct http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html dplyr.pdf p.65

Comment: `x %like% "y"` will match whole variable, while `x %like% "%y%"` will grep for pattern y in column x.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sql` to translate the expression directly into sql is one option.

```
sql_table %>% filter( sql("location LIKE 'A%' 
                           OR location LIKE 'B%' 
                           OR location LIKE 'C%'")
```

Which will inject the following into the WHERE statement of your query:

```
<SQL> location LIKE 'A%' OR location LIKE 'B%' OR location LIKE 'C%'
```