# R: efficient filter for character strings in multiple columns

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I have a data frame of names (first and last, some are capitalized some are not) and scores associated with each name:

```
df = data.frame(name = c("Mark Johnson","John Roberts","Sue mcguire","kat Long","dan Scott"), name2 = c("sam marks", "Mark Jones", "tim briar", "jonas Stark", "Mike Robinson"), score = c(2,3,4,5,5))

  name             name2         score
1 Mark Johnson     sam marks     2
2 John Roberts    Mark Jones     3
3  Sue mcguire     tim briar     4
4     kat Long   jonas Stark     5
5    dan Scott Mike Robinson     5
```

I want to be able to filter my data frame just by including a first or last name from *either* column, e.g.:

```
    df %>% filter(name %in% c("mark","john","Long","briar"))
```

I want to avoid using `grepl` and instead use `filter` and `%in%`.  However, this returns:

```
[1] name  score
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

instead of rows 1, 2, 3, and 4.  `name|name2` also didn't work.  Maybe it's because I need to do a `strsplit()` or something like this on the `name` and `name2` column and then re-combine.  However, this isn't very elegant and my `df` is actually millions of rows, so performance matters in my case.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

We can try with `filter_at`

```
pat <- paste(c("mark","john","Long","briar"), collapse="|")
df %>% 
   filter_at(vars(matches('name')), any_vars(grepl(pat, ., ignore.case = TRUE)))
```

If the pattern should match both the columns, then replace `any_vars` with `all_vars`

Comment: Would this work if my `df` is a sqlite table?  This is why I'd like to avoid using `grepl`, since it's not compatible.  This is the link I'm referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468166/grepl-for-dplyr-sql-table

Comment: @warship  It is very bad that there is incompatibility issues. If you want to use %in%, then you may need to split up to two columns using `separate`.  BTW which alll functions would work with sqlite

Comment: @warship Based on the link the `%like%` should work.  Have u tried

Comment: yes, there would still be an incompatibility with `grepl` and SQL :(

Comment: I agree on the incompatibility issue, perhaps @hadley will see this question and demystify...