# Dplyr filter with str_detect returns empty tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, roracle

I have a dplyr query in R that filters with str_detect to only get the cases that begins with the letters "KS", but it returns an empty tibble. I´m connected to an Oracle database using ROracle.

```
table <- tbl(con, "TABLE")

table %>% 
  filter(str_detect(COLUMN, "^KS"))
```

If I however use collect() to generate the tibble, it works:

```
table <- collect(tbl(con, "TABLE"))

table %>% 
  filter(str_detect(COLUMN, "^KS"))
```

Why is that? And how can I get it working without the collect? Some of the tables I need are to large to collect.

Update: 
If I change it to filter for a specific column value, like this: 
`table %>% 
filter(str_detect(COLUMN, "^KS"))`, 
it works. For some reason the regex doesn´t work without the collect().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468166/grepl-for-dplyr-sql-table

Comment: Thanks! I found an answer there, posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard Telford pointed me in the right direction with the link in the comments. It works if I instead use:

```
table <- tbl(con, "TABLE")

table %>% 
  filter(COLUMN %like% "%KS%")
```

Comment: The funny thing is that with a minimal loading of packages `filter(b,nom %LIKE% "^D")`returns nothing while `filter(collect(b),nom %LIKE% "^D")` exits on error failing to find function `%LIKE%`. This clearly demonstrates where the things are effectively evaluated.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove collect over. With %like% "%KS%" I get it working without the `collect()`.

Comment: Do you need '%KS' or '%KS%'? In the later case, my suggestion with locate was not adequate.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the translation of `str_detect` into a query to the data base :

```
b <- tbl(con,"pays")
filter(b,str_detect(nom,"^D")) %>% explain
#<SQL>
#SELECT *
#FROM "pays"
#WHERE (STRPOS("nom", '^D') > 0)


#<PLAN>
#Seq Scan on pays  (cost=0.00..5.31 rows=74 width=13)
#  Filter: (strpos(nom, '^D'::text) > 0)

b %>% filter(str_detect(nom, "^D")) %>% count
## Source:   lazy query [?? x 1]
## Database: postgres 9.6.1 [h2izgk@localhost:5432/postgres]
#      n
#  <dbl>
#1     0
```

Unfortunately STRPOS (I was using PostgreSQL) doesn't recognize the meaning of '^' and the query fails. So you should use another function, I found that `grepl  was fine :

```
filter(b,grepl("^D",nom)) %>% explain
#<SQL>
#SELECT *
#FROM "pays"
#WHERE (("nom") ~ ('^D'))


#<PLAN>
#Seq Scan on pays  (cost=0.00..4.76 rows=54 width=13)
#  Filter: (nom ~ '^D'::text)

b %>% filter(grepl("^D", nom))
## Source:   lazy query [?? x 3]
## Database: postgres 9.6.1 [h2izgk@localhost:5432/postgres]
#  nom      pays  code 
#  <chr>    <chr> <chr>
#1 DANEMARK 101   208  
#2 DOUALA   ""    120  
#3 DAKAR    ""    686  
#4 DJIBOUTI 399   262
```

And the result is correct.
In your example, `collect` solves the problem because it first downloads the whole table into the R memory and then appplies the `str_detect` without translating into SQL. But it is not efficient.

---

Comment: You're probably right, but in my case it doesn't work with grepl either. `Explain` gives me: `WHERE (GREPL('^KS', "AVTALE_NR"))`

Comment: This is because Oracle is not PostgreSQL. You could try Oracle operators and functions, perhaps something as : `table %>% filter(locate(COLUMN,"KS")==1) `.

Comment: Same problem with that one, but I´m quite sure you found the explanation. Something goes wrong in the translation that oracle doesn´t understand. For now I´m happy with the solution `%like% "%KS%"`.